# PHP Settings Error when trying to install Composer on Windows 7 machine

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I am receiving the following error when I download 'Composer-Setup.exe', double click the file and run the PHP Settings check.

Are there a couple of lines in the php.ini file that I need to fix? I am trying to run composer commands in my command prompt relating to an installation of Laravel on my Xampp server ('C:/Xampp/htdocs').

```
The PHP exe file you specified did not run correctly:
C:\Program Files (x86)\iis express\PHP\v7.0\php.exe

The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: C:\Program Files (x86)\iis express\PHP\v7.0\php.ini

A setting in your php.ini could be causing the problem: Either the 'extension_dir' value is incorrect or the dll does not exist.

Program Output:
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files (x86)\iis express\PHP\v7.0\ext\php_sqlsrv_72_ts.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files (x86)\iis express\PHP\v7.0\ext\php_mysql.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: Can we have the `php.ini`, so we would be able to help you with this ? especially the mentioned `entension_dir` part.

Comment: It's very clear, php cannot find the file to load.

Comment: The SQLServer database extension `php_sqlsrv_72_ts.dll` does not come with the default installation of PHP. You have to install that seperately along with a few other bits of software to make it all work

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/loading-the-php-sql-driver?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is from your php version, try upgrade your php version into 7++

Answer (score 0):

just install the php_pdo_sqlsrv_81_ts_x64.dll and it will work for u i did the same thing

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).